# WIX and commonAppDataFolder

Tags: wix

I am trying to create some empty folder in `COMMONAPPDATAFOLDER` during installation but it it not working, Can anybody please take a look at my code and let me know what is wrong Please?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
<?include sfmh_product.wxi?>
<Fragment>
  <FeatureGroup Id="FG_PROGRAMFILES">
      <FeatureRef Id="FT_PROGRAMFILES"/>
  </FeatureGroup>

  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">        
      <Merge  Id="CRT" 
              Language="0" 
              SourceFile="$(var.CRT_MSM)" 
              DiskId="1" />
      <Merge  Id="POLICY" 
              Language="0" 
              SourceFile="$(var.POLICY_MSM)" 
              DiskId="1" />

      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder" Name="ComApptDt" >
          <Directory Id="AppdataMfg" Name="Luttmann" >
              <Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="vmcNetFlix" />
          </Directory>
      </Directory>
   </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the `<CreateFolder .../>` command should work for you.

Comment: Thanks CreateFolder was missing.

Comment: Just a little note: you only need `CreateFolder` to create *empty* folders. If you install at least one file in the folder, windows installer will create it automatically.